# Modify XHR request response object (Json format) using Javascript

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I need some help trying to modify the response of an XHR request. My application is calling the api with the url:

```
https://xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx.com/api/bookings?locale=en
```

The api returns a objects in json format, where I need to replace this response with my own created json file (in the same object format)

I'm using Nightwatch, and have looked at this libery quite some time now.
[Xhook](https://github.com/jpillora/xhook)

I have already created the JSON file with name "reservations.json".

Have looked at the xhook.after method which look like this:

```
browser.injectScript('<a href="//cdn.rawgit.com/jpillora/xhook/1.3.1/dist/xhook.min.js">//cdn.rawgit.com/jpillora/xhook/1.3.1/dist/xhook.min.js</a>', function() {

        xhook.after(function(request, response) {
            if (request.url.match('api/bookings'))
                response.text = "testtest";
        });

    })
```

Hope someone will help me on this one.